# Is this interior location record setup crazy?

Tags: sync, location-recording, pro-tools, techniques

I've worked in post-production audio for just over 10 years, and I recently went freelance and somehow landed a gig producing a small interview shoot. The budget is tiny, so I'll be recording the sound. And while I have lots of post audio experience, I have zero location record experience.

Here's my plan for the shoot. Since all the interviewees will be seated in the same chair for each interview (filmed consecutively), I'm planning on putting the boom (Sen 416) on a mic stand with extension (no boom operator) and laving the interviewees as well. Because I'm very familiar with Pro Tools I'd like to record to hard drive using the preamps on my Mbox 2 Pro. In a perfect world, I'd like to grab word clock from the camera to time stamp the files. I'm not planning on running a back-up as if Pro Tools burps on a take, I can simply have the interviewee answer the question again. I'm specifically concerned about finding a camera with word clock out, and whether the whole plan is out to lunch or feasible.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! 

@Ryan, I'd like to go with the gear I have rather than renting more - I can get my hands on a Lafonte Preamp, and bypass the Mbox pres. I have yet to check out the location, I'll bring my 416 and if it sounds horrible, I'll take a look at the MKH50. The lav is really only as a safety - in my experience it's always better to have 'em and not need 'em than the other way around.

@Sound - Faffing around in post is what I do! I'd be concerned about going mbox -> camera, that would introduce sync issues due to latency, no?




Answer (score 1):

Like, Ryan said, i wouldn't recommend a 416. Good idea on the mic stand: i used to set up for the to-camera pieces for the australian 60 minutes, and we used a schoeps hyper(or super)cardioid, i can't remember what kind exactly, on a c-stand. As your interviewee may not sit completely still, something with a wide pickup pattern would be ideal.

As for the word clock; sorry, i'm not sure. Although i'd strongly suggest running straight into camera, or even out of the mbox into camera. That saves a bit of faffing around in post.

Answer (score 0):

btw how large is the room, also interesting if you can line up the walls w/ fabric to kill some of the reverb.. that may allow you to use the 416 with better results, but less than a boom op + boom would.